# Visual Studio 2015 GitHub extension only allow GitHub Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015, github-for-windows, github-enterprise

I can see this this is been asked before but with no answers but hoping someone can help.

Basically the option GitHub as highlighted in the image is not clickable. Only the GitHub Enterprise is available as an option. Any ideas how to swap between these 2? Any help greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This actually typically indicates that you're already logged in to a (non-enterprise) GitHub account.